# How to implement `append[A](x: List[A], y: List[A]): List[A]` in tail-recursive version?

Tags: scala, recursion, tail-recursion

Here is a recursive version of `append` for two lists:

```
def append[A](x: List[A], y: List[A]): List[A] = x match {
  case Nil => y
  case h :: t => h :: append(t, y)
}
```

How to convert it to tail-recursive version?

Answer (score 3):

Try this, though x is prepended in reverse order. is that intended?

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

@tailrec
def append[A](x: List[A], y: List[A]): List[A] = x match {
  case Nil => y
  case h :: t => append(t, h :: y)
}
```

If you want to prepend x in the order it comes with, you'ld have to do something like this:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def append[A](x: List[A], y: List[A]): List[A] = {
  @tailrec
  def innerAppend[A](x: List[A], y: List[A]): List[A] = x match {
    case Nil => y
    case h :: t => innerAppend(t, h :: y)
  }

  innerAppend(x.reverse, y)
}
```

Comment: This does not work, if you take the first function, you end up in an endless loop because `head :: x` is matched every time, not `x`. If you add parentheses around `x match { ... }`, your function is not tail recursive any more.

Comment: Right, should have paid more attention and test it. I'll redo my answer.

Comment: Reversing the first list and prepending it to the second, is probably the way to go yes. Maybe you could refactor it as an inline function (like you did with `appendTC` in your previous version) and call this inline function with `x.reverse`.

Answer (score 3):

The Scala Standard Library's `foldLeft` method for sequences is a tail-recursive method that allows for the creation of many core sequence operations which apply a binary operation between their elements.

Using `foldLeft`, here's how you'd implement your append method:

```
def append[A](x: List[A], y: List[A]): List[A] =
  x.reverse.foldLeft(y)((t, h) => h :: t) //Note the swapped order for h and t
```

which will return an appended list in the same order as given with the inclusion of `reverse`:

```
append(List(1,2,3), List(4,5,6))
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

The lack of `@tailrec` annotation is not meant to suggest that this is not tail-recursive; rather, `@tailrec` just won't detect properly when you are implementing a method or function through a tail-recursive method like `foldLeft`.

Unlike `foldLeft`, `foldRight` from the Standard Library will *not* create a tail-recursive method, though its syntax is easier to understand than having to reverse the input list and swap the parameters. That's why I prefer implementing a `foldRightViaFoldLeft` method, as it has a more user-friendly syntax, and keeps the tail-recursive properties:

```
def foldRVL[A,B](l: List[A], z: B)(f: (A,B) => B): B = //"RVL" == "Right Via Left"
  l.reverse.foldLeft(z)((b, a) => f(a, b)) //Note again that we are swapping a and b

def append[A](x: List[A], y: List[A]): List[A] =
  foldRVL(x, y)(_ :: _) //the swap in foldRVL means that we don't have swap when using it
```

This is still tail-recursive, but is now easier to read. There are many, many uses for `foldRVL`, and other `fold` methods. Use them wherever you can. For more information about folds, and a better explanation about their recursive properties, I recommend reading this post: [Scala Code Review: foldLeft and foldRight](http://oldfashionedsoftware.com/2009/07/10/scala-code-review-foldleft-and-foldright/).

I'd also highly recommend the book, *Functional Programming in Scala*, from which I learned how to properly `fold` things.